# Problem passing list attribute to HttpPost function

Tags: c#, json, post

This is a test function from my controller:

```
    [Route("TestingCurrentFunction")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FunctionTesting([FromBody] User user)
    {

        return Ok(user);
    }
```

When I call it with this JSON body:

```
{
   "name": "Igor",
   "username": "igor123",
   "password": "igrotheking123",
   "email": "igor@user.com",
   "tags": [
     {
        "genre": "superhero"
     }
   ]
}
```

it returns that it cannot read "tags[0].genre" and that genre field is required, but obviously there is genre. The class User in backend has a list of Tag objects, but Swagger detected them and generated this JSON body, I just filled it with random values. Why can't the function read tags?

Code for the User

```
using ProjekatN4J.DomainModel;
namespace ProjekatN4J
{
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }

    public User(string ime, string korIme, string sifra, string mejl)
    {
        this.name = ime;
        this.username = korIme;
        this.password = sifra;
        this.email = mejl;
        this.tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public User() 
    {
        this.tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}
```

}

And for Tag:

```
namespace ProjekatN4J.DomainModel
{
public class Tag
{
    public string genre { get; }

    public Tag(string genre)
    {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public Tag()
    {

    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, please show the code how you're calling it. What the value of `User user` is + the array and show how you've analyzed the "it returns that... " part.

Comment: Can you please add code for `User` type?

Comment: Updated it, but I think I saw an issue, the Tag class genre property does not have set method, I've fixed it now, and I will test it to see what happens, but it was probably that.

Comment: Yes, Tag class was the problem. Thank you guys.

Comment: XD you're welcome :-)